# SQL - speed up query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I currently use the following query which takes about 8 minute to return the result due to the volume of data (About 14 months). is there a way I can speed this up please?

The database in question is MySQL with InnoDb engine

```
select
    CUSTOMER as CUST,
    SUM(IF(PAGE_TYPE = 'C',PAGE_TYPE_COUNT,0)) AS TOTAL_C,
    SUM(IF(PAGE_TYPE = 'D',PAGE_TYPE_COUNT,0)) AS TOTAL_D
from
        PAGE_HITS
where
    EVE_DATE >= '2016-01-01' and EVE_DATE <= '2016-01-05'
    and SITE =  'P'
    and SITE_SERV like 'serv1X%'
group by
    CUST
```

Data is partitioned by 6 months. Every column that goes into where clause is indexed. There a quite some indexes & would be a big list to list here. Hence, just summarizing in words. With respect to this query, `EVE_DATE + PAGE_TYPE_COUNT` is one of the composite indexes & so are `CUST + SITE_SERV + EVE_DATE`, `EVE_DATE + SITE_SERV`, `EVE_DATE + SITE`,

The primary key is actually a dummy auto increment number. It isn't used to be honest. I don't have access to the explain plan. I'll see what best I can do for this.

I'd appreciate any help to improve this one please.

Comment: Can you specify what indexes are used (if any) and also what the structures look like? Primary Keys being used etc?

Comment: could you provide more details: number rows, indexes, storage engine and etc

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry I missed updating these details. Let me do this now.

Comment: Pls include the results of the explain as well.

Comment: Use existing query as an inner select and move `SITE_SERV like 'serv1X%'` to the outer query.

Comment: I've just updated the question with data storage structure to answer the above comments.

Comment: Without an `EXPLAIN` of the `SELECT` query, it'll be very hard (if not impossible) to tell which parts could be improved.

Comment: Alright. I'll have to wait to get access tot he explain. I'll come back here once I get there. In the meantime, if I do manage to resolve, I'll definitely let this forum know.

Comment: Your table is partitioned? Can you show the partition clause please?

Comment: Hello Thorsten - Thanks for jumping in. The data is partitioned by EVE_DATE. Each partition is 6 months worth of data. 14 months of data is spread across 3 partitions with the last of the partitions containing 2 months worth of data & growing as of date. Did I answer the query or am I way off. Please do let me know

Comment: Ah, okay so ist by `EVE_DATE ... PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ...` and not by `MONTH(EVE_DATE)` (which would have been two partitions only oblivious to the year). Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you have an auto increment key, then the keys should be in the same order with the dates. Why don't you try to fetch the results that are between the keys that are in the date range? e.g. `id BETWEEN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM PAGE_HITS WHERE EVE_DATE >= '2016-01-01' ORDER BY id ASC) AND (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM PAGE_HITS WHERE EVE_DATE <= '2016-01-05' ORDER BY id DESC)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, as the table range partition is on EVE_DATE, the DBMS should easily see which partition to read. So it's all about what index to use then.

There is one column you check for equality (`SITE = 'P'`). This should come first in your index. You can then add `EVE_DATE` and `SITE_SERV` in whatever order I guess. Thus your index should be able to locate the table records in question as fast as possible.

If, however, you add the other fields used in your query to your index, the table wouldn't even have to be read, because all data would be avaliable in the index itself:

```
create index on page_hits(site, eve_date, site_serv, customer, page_type, page_type_count);
```

This should be the optimal index for your query if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thank you heaps Thorsten. This improved performance by some measure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the data so I can't test the speed of this but I think it would be faster.

```
select
    CUSTOMER as CUST,
    SUM(PAGE_TYPE_COUNT * (PAGE_TYPE = 'C')) AS TOTAL_C,
    SUM(PAGE_TYPE_COUNT * (PAGE_TYPE = 'D')) AS TOTAL_D
from
        PAGE_HITS
where
    EVE_DATE >= '2016-01-01' and EVE_DATE <= '2016-01-05'
    and SITE =  'P'
    and SITE_SERV like 'serv1X%'
group by
    CUST
```

It worked just fine on my fiddle on MySql 5.6

Comment: Nice trick, I will definitely try this to simplify some queries I have; performance-wise, do you happen to have any metric?

Comment: Thankyou Xpy. This looks awesome. I'll surely use this elsewhere. n my case, there is no perf improvement. This is a real good one though

Answer (score 2):

The main optimization factor would be indexes. One should match your query as closely as possible, for example :

```
EVE_DATE, SITE, CUST, SITE_SERV
```

The order is important, at least for SITE_SERV as the last value; as you use `LIKE` on it you won't be using full value, which would degrade index efficiency for next columns.

You might also gain a tiny bit by removing the `IF` and returning type and count; maybe you can process/format this value in your front application?

Anyway, you should start with profiling your current query using `EXPLAIN` to see what goes wrong. If you can't, you could try reproducing structure, indexes and a few dummy data on a local DB, volume is irrelevant there.

Comment: Thank you Preuk. I'm happy to remove `IF`, how could I calculate the conditional `SUM` in an efficient way? Could you please help here?

Comment: I would say just select `PAGE_TYPE, SUM(PAGE_TYPE_COUNT) AS TOTAL` and manage the 'C' or 'D' case in your frontend application; but as I say it's probably not even worth it. Corrected a few typos, my sentence did not make any sense

Comment: Thank you Preuk. I'll use this suggestion elsewhere in my development. With respect to this question, I'm in need to process data int eh DB layer :(

Comment: Well if you can't skip the IF's, just keep them :) Check if you have an index with eve_date, site, cust and site_serv and if you can try to put this schema on a DB you can run `EXPLAIN`on, that's all I can recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Add these two indexes:

```
INDEX(site, date)
INDEX(site, site_serv)
```

The optimizer will look at the statistics and pick between them.  Roughly speaking the first one would be better if there are fewer rows with 'P' & DATEs in that range, than 'P' & 'serv1X%'.

Yes, the "covering" index that Thorsten might be better, but it has more fields than I like to put in an index.

`PARTITIONing` *might* help.  But there is too little info to say for sure.  The reason partitioning might help is that you have a "2-dimensional" lookup -- a date range and 'serv1X%'.  You would need to partition either on date or site_serv, then have the `PRIMARY KEY(site, ..., ...)` with the other of (date or site_serv) as the second column.  The rest of the columns would need to include both the partition key and some column to make it unique.  That gets so messy that I don't want to think it through.